# See all console messages in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have running

```
localhost === http://localhost:8000/app/templates/
```

and I would like to open it with PhantomJS so all procedures looks exactly like in real browser -> and in result i can see all the information that i normally see in browser console.

I couldn't find any information how to do it properly.

Untill now i have tried this pattern

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://localhost:8000/app/templates/
', function(status) {
});
```

but still I cannot see any console.logs which are used in js files which should be loaded together with get call to my localhost

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything. What do you expect to see? Open up the [API](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/) and see what you can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the console log, register the `onConsoleMessage` callback:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html